# Magento - Capture online from code

Tags: magento, capture, payment

often when customers complete and pay their order in our store, the order is set to processing but with the amount due still equal to the grand total and amount paid equal to zero. From the magento backend I can then create an invoice and capture the payment online, which solves this issue. Now I would like to do this automatically. Can anybody help me out with the coding?

I do succeed in creating the invoice, but I cannot find the right function to capture the payment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which payment method you have enabled, but it seems that you have to update your settings, and as example I will use **Authorize.net**.

If you go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods -> Authorize.net, you will see it's settings, and one of this settings is "Payment Action" with two options:

- Authorize Only
- Authorize and Capture

If the first option is selected, than Magento will not capture the order amount, but will check if there's enough funds on customer's Credit Card.

If the first option is selected, than Magento will check for available funds, and will capture order amount from customer's Credit Card.

**PayPal** has a similar options, and [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/44053/) is the related forum topic.

Comment: As it happens I've recently had the opposite problem and completely forgot to check this simple setting. Thank you.